# Is the extension-only file name actually the file name without extension as Node.js's ParsedPath considering?

Tags: node.js, path

```js
console.log(path.parse("C:\\projects\\SampleProject\\.env"));
```

Output:

```
{
  root: 'C:\\',
  dir: 'C:\\projects\\SampleProject',
  base: '.env',
  ext: '',
  name: '.env'
}
```

[Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathparsepath):

```
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┐
│          dir        │    base    │
├──────┬              ├──────┬─────┤
│ root │              │ name │ ext │
" C:\      path\dir   \ file  .txt "
└──────┴──────────────┴──────┴─────┘
```

So, the Node.js considering the `.env` as the file with name `.env` without extension.
Is is actually so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, the Node.js considering the .env as the file with name .env without extension. Is is actually so?

Yes. This is the expected behavior, see: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/22c39b1ddd/test/parallel/test-path-extname.js#L35

The current logic used for this is not very consistent in many languages, as there is no specification on how to handle this.

In PHP:

[image] https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

IN Rust:

[image] https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.extension